# Privacy and Security of Google Cloud Print

Tags: printing, google-cloud-print, hipaa

Our Physician and Nurses end-users need to print sensitive PHI (Patient Health Information) from their mobile devices (both iOS and Android) to local-network printers. We are considering Google Cloud Print as a cross-platform solution for this, however according to Google's documentation the print jobs, including the sensitive patient data, will be sent to Google's cloud and then forwarded to the on-site print server, and finally onto the selected printer. Apple's AirPrint protocol uses end-to-end encryption and the print data never leaves the local network, however as far as I have seen there is no cross-platform (iOS/Android) compatibility.

According to [Google Cloud Print FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/faq), "*Google Cloud Print temporarily stores the data (in a secure manner, only accessible by the user) and print job information as part of the transfer process to the printer. Once the data has reached the printer, all the data is deleted from Google’s servers… all data transfer between apps and Google Cloud Print, and between Google Cloud Print and printers, is over an encrypted connection*"

Does Google have access to the sensitive patient data or is it encrypted even to Google's eyes? How can we confirm if Google Cloud Print is [HIPAA-compliant](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/security/laws-regulations/index.html)?

Is there a white-paper out there on Google Cloud Print privacy and security?

Comment: I really wish someone had answered this for you. You may have figured it out for yourself, and if so, I'd love an update. I'm going to keep digging and if I find an answer will try to return here to add it.

Comment: We did not figure this out and indefinitely tabled this due to security and privacy concerns unfortunately.